# How can I stop certain extensions from running in the background after Chrome is closed?

Tags: google-chrome

After closing Chrome, certain extensions keep running on the background (like Drive or Hangouts).

Without disabling a extension, can I control which ones can keep running after Chrome is closed?

Comment: Disable the ones you don't want.

Comment: I do not want to disable them, I use them but only while Chrome is open.

Comment: This might be helpful: https://www.maketecheasier.com/stop-google-chrome-running-background/

Comment: What OS platform are you using? I'm asking, because I'm looking through the source code for Chrome and need to focus my search.

Comment: @Lifeiscomplex Windows 10, thank you

Answer (score 3):

By default Chrome allows applications/extensions to keep running in the background to provide their services like updates and notifications. This is handy for keeping you updated with notifications on Facebook or a new email in Gmail.

You can stop Chrome from running in the background from the Chrome settings.

1. Click on Chrome’s main menu and select “Settings.”
2. Scroll down and click on “Show advanced settings.”
3. Scroll down to the extreme bottom and uncheck the option “Continue running background apps when Google Chrome is closed” under the “System” heading.

same with images is here https://www.maketecheasier.com/stop-google-chrome-running-background/

Comment: Thanks but this will disallow all of my extensions from running on the background. I only wanted to disallow certain extensions, not all of them.

Comment: Thank you. I have added a bounty to the question.

Comment: Thanks @Yevgeniy Afanasyev!

Answer (score 2):

Use the chrome task manager to stop the extensions you want.

To open chrome’s task manager, click the “**More**” button (*three dots*), hover over “**More Tools**,” and then click on “**Task Manager**.” Alternatively, press **Shift+Esc** on Windows or **Search+Esc** on Chrome OS to open Task Manager.

Chrome task manager shows the list of open web pages and chrome extensions that are running.

[image: google chrome task manager]

Select the extensions you want to stop and then press **End process**

But if you only want to disable them from running in the background after closing Chrome:

> Windows:

`Ctrl + Shift + Esc`

> Mac:

1. Hit Command+Spacebar to bring up the Spotlight search field.
2. Type in “Activity Monitor”
3. Hit the Return key when “Activity Monitor” populates in the spotlight results.
4. You are now in Activity Monitor where you can manage and manipulate tasks.

Select the extensions process and press the `End task` button (Windows) or select the process and press the `x` button in the upper left.

Comment: This will stop the extension completely, I only wanted to disabled them from running in the background after closing Chrome.

Answer (score -2):

You can click the 3 bar on the far right side of the chrome; click settings; click extensions right above that; then disable which ever extensions you do not want running.  Often times if you have a ton of add-ons/extensions disabling these can speed up browsing.  Happy surfing!

Comment: Maybe I wasn't being clear. I'm trying to avoid certain extensions from running in the background after Chrome is closed but without disabling them.